# Index out of bounds when using Realm with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, realm, swiftui

I've been playing around with SwiftUI a bit and have been writing a small meal planner/todo list style app.
I was able to get Realm working with SwiftUI and wrote a small wrapper object to get Realm change notifications to update the UI.
This works great for adding items and the UI gets properly updated. However, when deleting an item using swipe to delete or other methods, I get an index out of bounds error from Realm.

Here's some code:

**ContentView:**

```swift
    struct ContentView : View {

    @EnvironmentObject var userData: MealObject
    @State var draftName: String = ""
    @State var isEditing: Bool = false
    @State var isTyping: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        List {
            HStack {
                TextField($draftName, placeholder: Text("Add meal..."), onEditingChanged: { editing in
                    self.isTyping = editing
                },
                onCommit: {
                    self.createMeal()
                    })
                if isTyping {
                    Button(action: { self.createMeal() }) {
                        Text("Add")
                    }
                }
            }
            ForEach(self.userData.meals) { meal in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailMealView(ingredientsObject: IngredientsObject(meal: meal))) {
                    MealRow(name: meal.name)
                }
            }.onDelete(perform: delete)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Meals"))
    }

    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        guard let index = offsets.first else {
            return
        }
        let mealToDelete = userData.meals[index]
        Meal.delete(meal: mealToDelete)
        print("Meals after delete: \(self.userData.meals)")
    }
}
```

And the MealObject wrapper class:

```swift
final class MealObject: BindableObject {
    let willChange = PassthroughSubject<MealObject, Never>()

    private var token: NotificationToken!
    var meals: Results<Meal>

    init() {
        self.meals = Meal.all()
        lateInit()
    }

    func lateInit() {
        token = meals.observe { changes in
            self.willChange.send(self)
        }
    }

    deinit {
        token.invalidate()
    }
}
```

I was able to narrow the issue down to

```swift
   ForEach(self.userData.meals) { meal in
      NavigationLink(destination: DetailMealView(ingredientsObject: IngredientsObject(meal: meal))) {
      MealRow(name: meal.name)
     }
   }
```

It seems like self.userData.meals isn't updating, even though when checking the change notification in MealObject it shows the correct deletions and the meals variable in MealObject correctly updates as well.

*Edit: Also to add, the deletion does actually happen and when launching the app again, the deleted item is gone. It seems like SwiftUI gets confused about the state and tries to access the deleted item after willChange gets called.

*Edit 2: Found one workaround for now, I implemented a method checking whether the object currently exists in Realm:

```swift
    static func objectExists(id: String, in realm: Realm = try! Realm()) -> Bool {
        return realm.object(ofType: Meal.self, forPrimaryKey: id) != nil
    }
```

Called like this

```swift
            ForEach(self.userData.meals) { meal in
                if Meal.objectExists(id: meal.id) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailMealView(ingredientsObject: IngredientsObject(meal: meal))) {
                        MealRow(name: meal.name)
                    }
                }
            }.onDelete(perform: delete)
```

Not very pretty but it gets the job done until I find the real cause for the crash.

Comment: can you show exact line where you get the crash? In your `I was able to narrow the issue down to` section there is no subscript calling on array

Comment: This will look as totally unrelated, but is your keyboard showing when you try to delete? I've seen cases where hiding the keyboard right before deleting, prevents the out of bounds.

Comment: @Lu_ Yeah that's the confusing part, the crash actually happens in the Realm code, the last few things I can see on the stacktrace are Results.subscript.getter, [RLMResults ObjectAtIndex:] followed by Realm throwing the error.
I have this suspicion that SwiftUI tries to access the already deleted element in ForEach which is what's causing the crash.

Comment: firEach just go one element after another, It should be impossible to rash (but I didn't saw implementation), id you try using List?

Comment: I see where you delete the meal from the array but I am not seeing where you are deleting the object from Realm. Best practice if you are using an observer pattern is to delete it from Realm. That will trigger an event where the object can then be deleted from the array, and then the tableView refreshed. I may be overlooking something however.

Comment: I've got the same crash - could it be because we've got `objectWillChange` (_will_) being called after the change has been made?

Answer (score 5):

With Realm Cocoa 5.0, you now just need to freeze whatever collection you pass to `ForEach`:

```swift
ForEach(self.userData.meals.freeze()) { meal in
    NavigationLink(destination: DetailMealView(ingredientsObject: IngredientsObject(meal: meal))) {
        MealRow(name: meal.name)
    }
}
```

---

Pre 5.0 answer:

How SwiftUI's ForEach appears to work is that after getting sent objectWillChange() it iterates over the collection it was previously given and the new collection it is given, and then diffs them. This only works properly for immutable collections, but Realm collections are mutable and live-updating. In addition, the objects *in* the collection also change, so the obvious workaround of copying the collection into an Array doesn't full work either.

The best workaround I've come up with is something like the following:

```
// helpers
struct ListKey {
    let id: String
    let index: Int
}
func keyedEnumeration<T: Object>(_ results: Results<T>) -> [ListKey] {
    return Array(results.value(forKey: "id").enumerated().map { ListKey(id: $0.1 as! String, index: $0.0) })
}

// in the body
ForEach(keyedEnumeration(self.userData.meals), id: \ListKey.id) { key in
    let meal = self.userData.meals[key.index]
    NavigationLink(destination: DetailMealView(ingredientsObject: IngredientsObject(meal: meal))) {
        MealRow(name: meal.name)
    }
}
```

The idea here is to extract the array of primary keys up front and give that to SwiftUI so that it can diff them without having to touch Realm, rather than trying to read from the "old" collection that's actually been updated.

A future version of Realm will have support for frozen collections/objects that'll be a better fit for the semantics that SwiftUI wants, but no ETA on that.

Comment: Right now, for a temporary solution I'm trying to convert is to array, besides all the performance penalty it seems to work ok. Do you have any advice against it? In the meantime might I ask you wether you have any confirmation on you last statement?

Comment: > PS: in order to work properly it has to be sorted after the conversion

Comment: Merely converting to an array will result in crashes if you delete objects, as the old array will hold references to now invalidated objects.

Comment: Actually the one thing this handles well is deletion. But now you see it seems weird, so I might have to look in to the reasons why it works when it should not.

Comment: nevermind, I have adopted your approach, it seems to be the best right now. I, also have modified it to be index safe and removed the requirement for a stored "id": https://gist.github.com/Gujci/8307ab63bec7143486cab8dfa258acfd

Answer (score 0):

I created a helper function based off Thomas's answer. This way, you can change all your ForEach references to ForEach:

```
public struct ForEachRealm<C: RandomAccessCollection, T: Object, Content: View>: View where C.Element == T, T: Identifiable, C.Index == Int {
    let results: C
    let fn: (Int, T) -> Content

    public init(_ results: C, @ViewBuilder fn: @escaping (T) -> Content) {
        self.results = results
        self.fn = { _, object in return fn(object) }
    }

    public init(_ results: C, @ViewBuilder fn: @escaping (Int, T) -> Content) {
        self.results = results
        self.fn = fn
    }

    public var body: some View {
        ForEach(keyedEnumeration(results)) { holder -> Content in
            return self.fn(holder.index, self.results[holder.index])
        }
    }

    // From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57160790/index-out-of-bounds-when-using-realm-with-swiftui
    struct ListKey<T: Identifiable>: Identifiable {
        let id: T.ID
        let index: Int
    }

    func keyedEnumeration(_ results: C) -> [ListKey<T>] {
        return Array(results.enumerated().map { ListKey(id: $0.element.id, index: $0.offset) })
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some sample code on how to use this code snippet. Thanks!

Comment: In your view body, you can do something like: `ScrollView { ForEachRealm(self.myRealmResults) { Text($0.textProperty) } }`

Comment: This will create a scroll view with a list of `Text` elements which have the `textProperty` of each realm object (assuming that's a valid property of your object).

Comment: @plivesey - this does not seem to work with Xcode 11.4 - complains about being unable to infer the parameters