# Delete element in Realm List in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, realm

My model structure is:

```
class Deck: Object, Codable, Identifiable{

     @objc private (set) dynamic var id = NSUUID().uuidString
     @objc dynamic var title: String = ""
     @objc dynamic var image: String = ""
     @objc dynamic var created: Date = Date()
     var cards = RealmSwift.List<Card>()

     override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
         return "id"
    }
}

@objcMembers class Card: Object, Codable, Identifiable{

    @objc dynamic var id: String = NSUUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var character: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var pinyin: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var translation: String = ""
    let deck = RealmSwift.LinkingObjects<Deck>(fromType: Deck.self, property: "cards")

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

So I have a deck with a list of several cards. When I want to delete an element in the `cards` List i always got the error message `RLMException', reason: 'Index 1 is out of bounds (must be less than 1).'` (except when I delete the last element in the list. That works fine).

```
List {
    ForEach(deckItemViewModel.cards){ cell in // <---- out of bounds index message
        CardCell(flashcard: cell)
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        }
        .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in decksViewModel.deleteCard(card: deckItemViewModel.cards[indexSet.first!])
        })
    }
```

After I've found [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58243808/14677894) I changed my code to  `ForEach(deckItemViewModel.cards.freeze()){ cell in`and it's working fine. But now when I want to delete the whole deck with these frozen cards, my app crashes. How can I solve this problem? Is there any way to "unfreeze" them?

EDIT: @Jay

```
func deleteCard(_ obj: Object){
    do {
        try realm.safeWrite {
            realm.delete(obj)
        }
    } catch {
        NSLog("error deleting object: %@", [error])
    }
}
```

`deckItemViewModel.cards` is actually just the list of cards in the deck.

```
Class DeckItemViewModel: ObservableObject {
   @Published var deck: Deck

   init(deck: Deck){
       self.deck = deck
    }

    ...

    var cards: RealmSwift.List<Card>{
        return deck.cards
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure your updated approach with to deleting with .freeze is the correct move. However, you've got `deckItemViewModel.card` and also `deskViewModel.deleteCard` and we don't know what those are so it's hard to tell. Also this is almost always a bad idea `indexSet.first!` as your force unwrapping an optional with ! and it may be nil - hence your crash. For your second question; You can't delete frozen objects like that. Can you clarify and update your question so we can have a clearer picture of what's going on?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've forgotten to add this code as well. Hope my edit helps you now. "I am not sure your updated approach with to deleting with .freeze is the correct move." -> I don't think it's a good solution as well, but it was a quick solution that helped me in that case. I appreciate any advice!

Comment: I think the issue is that while you're deleting the card from Realm, that object still exists in the array. However, it's still very hard to tell as the line you're indicating as throwing the error doesn't have and Index like that - are you sure it's not the .onDelete code that's throwing the error?

Comment: The error in XCode is shown at the `ForEach` line, but yes, the error appears when I delete the element. So the origin is probably the `.onDelete` function. But it's really strange that this error doesn't appear when I delete the last element in the list.